# cannot persist audit data with hibernate envers when using UUID as primary key (varchar)

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, mariadb, uuid, hibernate-envers

I am using spring boot 2.7.2 and hibername 5.6.9.Final. I use Mariadb and the primary keys are defined as Varchar(255).
I store uuid for primary keys and now decided to use hibernate envers which I realize it needs either numeric id or some complicated configurations to be able to use UUID.

I am not sure but based on my researches either I have to upgrade hibernate/spring library or change the primary keys to numeric type. can someone help me with the best solution?

POM.XML

```
<!--    Hibernate Envers-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
      <version>5.6.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

here is the entity definition:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "number_directory_entry")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Audited
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class NumberDirectoryEntry {

  public static final String ENTRY_URIS = "uriList";  // should be similar to the field name always
  public static final String ENTRY_STATUS = "status";
  public static final String ENTRY_NAME = "entry_name";
  public static final String FRMCS_LABEL = "frmcs_label";
  public static final String ENTRY_TYPE_ID = "entry_type_id";
  public static final String ENTRY_DESCRIPTION = "description";

  public static final String ENTITY_ID = "id";
  public static final String ENTITY_VERSION = "version";
  public static final String CREATED_BY = "created_by";
  public static final String CREATE_TIME = "created_date";
  public static final String MODIFY_USER = "modified_by";
  public static final String MODIFY_TIME = "modified_date";

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
  @Type(type="uuid-char")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
  @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false)
  private UUID id;

  @Column(name = ENTRY_NAME, nullable = false)
  private String name;
...
}
```

and here is the exception based on this configuration I get. if I change id to String I get other exception.

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: The database returned no natively generated identity value; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: The database returned no natively generated identity value
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:331)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:566)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at itssc.ktr.erpm.service.impl.NumberDirectoryServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$37fea415.saveNewNumberDirectoryEntry(<generated>)
    at itssc.ktr.erpm.service.worker.numberdirectory.CreateNumberDirectoryEntryWorker.execute(CreateNumberDirectoryEntryWorker.java:53)
    at org.camunda.bpm.client.topic.impl.TopicSubscriptionManager.handleExternalTask(TopicSubscriptionManager.java:155)
    at org.camunda.bpm.client.topic.impl.TopicSubscriptionManager.lambda$acquire$0(TopicSubscriptionManager.java:110)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:4204)
    at org.camunda.bpm.client.topic.impl.TopicSubscriptionManager.acquire(TopicSubscriptionManager.java:105)
    at org.camunda.bpm.client.topic.impl.TopicSubscriptionManager.run(TopicSubscriptionManager.java:89)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: The database returned no natively generated identity value
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper.getGeneratedIdentity(IdentifierGeneratorHelper.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3279)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3885)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:330)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:672)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:665)
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.revisioninfo.DefaultRevisionInfoGenerator.saveRevisionData(DefaultRevisionInfoGenerator.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.synchronization.AuditProcess.getCurrentRevisionData(AuditProcess.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.synchronization.AuditProcess.executeInSession(AuditProcess.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.synchronization.AuditProcess.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(AuditProcess.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.synchronization.AuditProcessManager$1.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(AuditProcessManager.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue$BeforeTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:954)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:525)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2426)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

I've tried changing the Id to String or back to UUID, or I also changed the **GeneratedValue** annotation values and nothing changed.

by removing @Type(type="uuid-char") I get this error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:259)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:566)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at itssc.ktr.erpm.service.impl.NumberDirectoryServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$caa9b37f.saveNewNumberDirectoryEntry(<generated>)
    at itssc.ktr.erpm.service.worker.numberdirectory.CreateNumberDirectoryEntryWorker.execute(CreateNumberDirectoryEntryWorker.java:53)
    at org.camunda.bpm.client.topic.impl.TopicSubscriptionManager.handleExternalTask(TopicSubscriptionManager.java:155)
    at org.camunda.bpm.client.topic.impl.TopicSubscriptionManager.lambda$acquire$0(TopicSubscriptionManager.java:110)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:4204)
    at org.camunda.bpm.client.topic.impl.TopicSubscriptionManager.acquire(TopicSubscriptionManager.java:105)
    at org.camunda.bpm.client.topic.impl.TopicSubscriptionManager.run(TopicSubscriptionManager.java:89)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3375)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3908)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1407)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:489)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3290)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=145) Incorrect string value: '\x97\x90@9\xA5d...' for column `erpm_db`.`number_directory_entry`.`id` at row 1
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.export.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:280)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.export.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:368)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.message.ClientMessage.readPacket(ClientMessage.java:137)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.readPacket(StandardClient.java:833)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.readResults(StandardClient.java:772)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.readResponse(StandardClient.java:691)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.execute(StandardClient.java:634)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:95)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:334)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:311)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Which MariaDB version? UUID has been a [datatype](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/uuid-data-type/) since 10.7. I'm not familiar enough with hibernate however it should be a SQL only solution and not complicated like [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TdKFEkIi). Maybe something like `@Column(columnDefinition = "uuid default (uuid())")`

Comment: Found [HHH-15503 Add UUID support for MariaDB 10.7](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15503) and [its implementation](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/5282/files). Is `@Type(type = "uuid")` sufficient?

Comment: with `@Column(columnDefinition = "uuid default (uuid())")` I get runtime exception that I showed in the ruestion. the second exception. with the `@Type(type = "uuid")` I get compile time exception that it `Could not load requested class : uuid`

Comment: by the way I am using MariaDb 10.6 and can not change it at the moment.

Comment: the latest error is:  `(conn=327) Incorrect string value: '\xD8\xF7\xEB\xBED\x84...' for column `erpm_db`.`number_directory_entry`.`id` at row 1` as id is defined as varchar in db and I send `UUID.randomUUID()` value

Comment: Apologies for the explanation without solution, the error relates to that its being treated in a characters set, probably utf8, however what the string of bytes isn't actually utf8. A workaround is to make it a `varbinary` rather than a `varchar` in the database as this appears to be an error  on inserting. Also I'm hoping `randomUUID()` is generating UUIDv4 (check an online tool) rather than a 128 random bits presented as uuid.